# how to use useState react hook for more than one element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, use-state

I'm building a full-stack website using mern (mongo express reactjs and nodejs) for the first time in using react hooks.
So I have bootstrap cards with a collapse button to hide card body text, but I have 6 cards and the collapse button works with the useState hook, in a way that onClick sets the expand property to false and vise versa.
My question is that should I use 6 useState hooks for the 6 cards? or in any way, there's some solution.
ps. that if the same hook is used on all cards then onClick will expand all cards.

here's my code of one useState and one card:

```
const [open1, setOpen1] = useState(false);
 <Button

        onClick={() => setOpen1(!open1)}
        aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
        aria-expanded={open1}
      >
        click
      </Button>
      <Collapse in={open1}>
        <div id="example-collapse-text">
        This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
        </div>
      </Collapse>
```

Comment: Apply your logic by making a numeric value for useState , for eg : const [open, setOpen] = useState(1);

Comment: @Ajith can you clarify more? since the Boolean is for the aria-expanded prop that expands and collapses on true and false

Comment: I have added an answer now, Could you please check and let me know

Comment: I think a more modular way of solving this would be defining your card as a React component separately. Each card would have its own state and you can reuse it indefinitely. The onClick logic would also be handled inside that component.

Comment: @mkemaltas well this is some good fix thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is , make a folder named component (name not necessarily be same but this is very much followed). In that folder make you card component like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const card = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const collapseListener = () => {
    setOpen((prvState) => !prvState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={collapseListener}>{/* button to collapse */}</button>
      <collable collapse={isOpen}>
        {/* your collapasble component */}
        <h1>{prop1}</h1>
        <h1>{prop2}</h1>
      </collable>
    </div>
  );
};

export default card;
```

Then you can import this card component from anywhere and can use it like this

```
<Card prop1={'first'} prop2={'second'}  />
```

Answer (score 2):

well this was solved by making a component for the card and then using it as an jsx element.

```
export default function DepartmentCard() {
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

<Button
onClick={() => setOpen(open)}
aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
aria-expanded={(open === 1)? true : false}>
click
</Button>
<Collapse in={open}>
<div id="example-collapse-text">
This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural
    lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
</div>
</Collapse>
}
```

btw it's the same code but instead of using it 6 times, I made as one component, and used the component tag 6 times.
but the difference is that now each component has it's own state

Example:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
<DepartmentCard/>
<DepartmentCard/>
<DepartmentCard/>
<DepartmentCard/>
<DepartmentCard/>
<DepartmentCard/>
</div>
```

or you can simply use the map() function or a loop to render the 6 cards.
and you can use props to change the body of each card.

Comment: Can you share the code also as answer

Comment: yes yes for sure

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following logic ?

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(1);
<Button
onClick={() => setOpen(1)}
aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
aria-expanded={(open === 1)? true : false}>
click
</Button>
<Collapse in={(open === 1)? true : false}>
<div id="example-collapse-text">
This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural
    lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
</div>
</Collapse>

<Button
  onClick={() => setOpen(2)}
  aria-controls="example-collapse-text"
  aria-expanded={(open === 2)? true : false}>
  click
</Button>
<Collapse in={(open === 2)? true : false}>
  <div id="example-collapse-text">
  This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural
      lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.
  </div>
</Collapse>
```

Comment: well this works but it is only for expanding; since if I want collapse it I should expand another just to change the number in the useState.

Comment: You can also  follow modular approach to reduce repeat coding for each button and collapse (This will be the recommeded way)

Comment: @FirasSCMP Please upvote if it helps you